# Making a copy of Symfony project on server?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to copy an existing Symfony project to another directory, so I can test changes before applying them to the live version.

I get a 404 error whenever I try to access the project on the copy via `app.php` or `app_dev.php`, and I can't pin down why. The live project is in a folder called `representation/mvcrep` and the copy is in a folder called `representation_dev/mvcrep`, and they are both on the same hierarchy in the directory tree.

I've already successfully cleared the cache for both the `dev` and `prod` environments in the copy, with no decipherable result. There are no errors in the Symfony logs, and the 404 is one for the site not for Symfony, so I'm assuming it's a problem with the server. Both projects have the exact same permissions as well.

Anyone have any clue to what the problem could be?

Edit: To clarify, the `web` directory has not been renamed or modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you reported that you use two subfolders in the same virtual host, the web server configuration is probably not the issue here.

Since I suspect permissions issues, I suggest you to debug by creating a base text file in the `/representation_dev/mvcrep/web` folder, e.g. `hello.txt`, and see if you can get that via browser.

If not, check the permissions on the newly created folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough info for a precise answer, but this sounds definitely more like a server configuration issue than a Symfony issue,

If you make a copy of your Symfony folder, you also need to create a new web site that points to the new installation.

I.e. previously you browsed the site

```
http://representation.local/
```

which has its web root in

```
.../representation/mvcrep/web
```

Now you need to create a new site

```
http://representation_dev.local/
```

which has its web root in

```
.../representation_dev/mvcrep/web
```

Comment: I am accessing the site directly through the `web` directory, like `http://example.com/representation/mvcrep/web`, so I shouldn't need another sub domain for this purpose. However, thank you for being the only person to respond so far.

Comment: Ok. Now for debug, I'd start by creating a base text file in the  `/representation_dev/mvcrep/web` folder, e.g. "hello.txt", and see if you can get that. If not, I bet it may be permissions issues.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Nearly every other directory had the exact permissions as the live version EXCEPT the web directory, which was not set as executable by the world. Thanks.

Comment: I thank you for your upvote but my answer is not the correct one. I will create a new one so you can upvote that one instead.